# Using Devise Gem with namespaces throwing ActionController::RoutingError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, namespaces, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Ok, I've seen a ton of different answers for how to get Devise working when using namespaces in your app, but none of them are working for me.

I have my app split up into three namespaces

Home (the public landing pages)
Account (the logged in profile/account of the user)
Admin (the admin backend which isn't written yet)

I've also split up all the partials into a `base` folder in each namespace. So each of my controllers inherit from the `BaseController` which inherits from the `ApplicationController`:

```
   module Account
      class UsersController < BaseController
      end
   end
```

And I created a `sessions_controller.rb` in both account and home that inherits from the devise sessions controller like this:

```
module Account
  class SessionsController < BaseController < Devise::SessionsController
  end
end
```

The goal is to have a login/ registration form in the Home namespace that lets users login to the users controller that is in the account namespace.

Right now when I click on the link generated by:

`<%= link_to "register", new_user_registration_path %>`

I'm getting

```
ActionController::RoutingError at /users/sign_up
uninitialized constant Account::RegistrationsController
```

My routes.rb file looks like this:

```
    scope :module => "account" do  
        devise_for :users, :controllers => { :sessions => "account/sessions" }
        resource :users
      end

      scope :module => "home" do
        resources :home, :about, :jobs, :terms, :privacy, :android_availability, :about, :contact
      end

      get "home/index"
      root :to => 'home::home#index'
end
```

The home controllers use a home layout and the account controllers use the application layout. I specify `layout "home"` in the home controllers, but I don't specify `layout "application"` in the account controllers because application is the default layout rails looks for.

Ok. I think I've covered all my bases. Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks!

EDIT:

Ok, I've added a `registrations_controller.rb` file to the account namespace in the same way as the `sessions_controller.rb` file described above.

I also updated the `routes.rb` file:

```
scope :module => "account" do  
    devise_for :users, :controllers => { 
      :sessions => "account/sessions",
      :registrations => "account/registrations" }
    resource :users
  end
```

Now I'm getting a new error that I don't understand. Here it is:

```
NoMethodError at /users/sign_up
undefined method `action' for Account::RegistrationsController:Class
```

It says the undefined method 'action' is in `(gem) actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb` which doesn't make any sense.

Specifically is says the problem is here:

```
def dispatch(controller, action, env)
  controller.action(action).call(env)
end
```

EDIT 2:

Here is the code from my `registrations_controller.rb`

```
module Account
  class RegistrationsController < BaseController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  end
end
```

EDIT 3:

```
module Account
  class BaseController < ApplicationController
  end
end
```

Ok, the above is my `base_controller.rb`, which just inherits from the `ApplicationController`. All the other controllers inherit from `BaseController`. Because I've split my app into three namespaces, the base_controller is there to tell the other controllers in the namespace that the partials are in a folder named `base` within their namespace. As shown in [this RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/269-template-inheritance?view=asciicast)

I get a missing partial error if I don't incude the `BaseController` because the devise controllers can't find the partials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read your errors! :-)

For starters, looks like you need to define an `Account::RegistrationsController`, the same way you did your `Account::SessionsController`.

Comment: Really?! I thought the SessoinsController inherited from the rest of the controllers, so I wouldn't have to do that. I'll do it now and see what happens. Thanks!

Comment: I updated my question with the new error I am getting after adding the RegistrationsController.

Comment: Can you post your `Account::RegistrationsController` class and path? That filename above is capitalized, but I'm not sure if that was a mistype.

Comment: I just updated my question with the registrations_controller.rb Class. The registrations_controller.rb file is lower case. That was a typo. I fixed it. What do you mean by the path? the routes.rb roue? Or what I posted in EDIT 2?

Comment: Don't know how I missed this before: Ruby doesn't have multiple inheritance.  In this case your `Account::RegistrationsController` will need to inherit from `Devise::RegistrationsController`, so you might consider making `BaseController` a mixin if you need it here.

Comment: Ohhhh. Ok. So I've been doing some reading on mixins, and the problem is the BaseController is just there to tell all the other controllers where the partials are stored. namespace/base/_partial.html.erb so there isn't a class or namespace to include with a mixin. Does that make sense? Should I just save this for an office hours?

Comment: Might as well just post `BaseController` here, and we can figure out how to convert it.

Comment: Ok, I added my BaseController, and some information about why it's set up the way it is.